# Linux bootloader on USB-stick, load different kernel depending on hardware

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, bootloader, disk-encryption

I'm experimenting with a setup where I keep my kernel and initrd on a USB stick, and thus I can keep **everything** on the actual computers fully encrypted. Nothing is stored in clear text, and nothing can be tampered with.

I want to use the same USB stick for booting up multiple machines, and it would be real fancy if the boot loader could decide to load a different kernel/initrd/rootfs depending on which hardware I'm booting, and if it could detect this automatically using some sort of manual rules (perhaps hard drive UUID or similar).

Any ideas how I could create a setup like this? I could set up grub or similar with a simple menu that I can use when booting, but it would be nice if it could detect this. It would only need to boot linux variants.